# Rails - Creating a new record using nested forms and using it as a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, nested-forms

That is the best title I can think of. To use a popular example, I'm using nested forms to create a survey that has many questions that have many answers. Following [Ryan Bates Railscast on Nested Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) I have successfully created my form that lets me add a new survey, dynamically add/remove questions and dynamically add/remove answers to those questions.
Now, let's say I also have a user model,  a user has many surveys, and I create a survey for a particular user. My question is, if I want to create another survey for that same user, and only a couple things are going to change compared to the first survey, is there a way to call back the previous survey, sort of like a template for future ones that I can tweak or change slightly instead of creating it all over again?

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured this out already, but here goes.

If you have a properly established has_many relationship between Users and Surveys, you can get to a users surveys in your controller:

```
user = User.find(123)  # 123, whatever your user_id is 
@most_recent_survey = user.surveys.order('created_at DESC').first
```

Which you will then have access to in your views to modify in whatever ways you see fit.

ian.